# "You do not have any ID pack" on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have created a new Apple developer account and I am trying to create a new APP module on iTunes Connect to upload my APP.

I could upload APPs in other account developer accounts and I did not have any problem. Instead of that, now I am getting an error message when I press on "+" button and "New APP" option.

This is the message I am getting:

> You do not have any ID pack for iOS apps that meets the requirements. [Register one here](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/).

**Note:** I have translated it from my language so it maybe its not literally as I put before.

I have created a new distribution certificate for the new app developer account and looked because maybe I should add a further configuration on Xcode but I could not see anything that worked for me.

How can I add a new app properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to create a new app ID in apple developer account portail :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz7VLJsUViniWWh2b3BfdnlKQ1E.

Please let me know if that solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

You can only add/create an app in iTunes Connect, if you first registered the App on the Apple Developer Portal:

1. Head over to: https://developer.apple.com/account and click on "Certificates, IDs & Profiles"

[image]

2. Click on "App IDs" in the Identifiers section and then on the little "Plus" sign at the top.

[image]

3. Then you can register your app. Once that's done, you can create the app on iTunes Connect and choose from a dropdown the bundle ID

[image]